# Matlab getting cursor info with no click

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have Matlab application where the user needs to click on a point in a graph, and then confirm the click in a message box. I'm using `getCursorInfo` to get the current clicked location. If the user doesn't confirm the point selection, another point should be selected.

The problem is that sometimes after the user choose 'No' in the message box, getCursorInfo returns a new position without requiring the user to click on the mouse. It is as if getCursorInfo thinks the mouse button is continuously down.

Here is a minimal sample of code that demonstrates this - after the 3rd or 4th time the message box is shown, Matlab thinks the mouse button is down and changes the cursor position without any clicks.

```
fig = figure;
data = peaks();
plot(data);

old_pos = [-2 -2]
cur_pos = old_pos
while 1
    datacursormode on
    dcm = datacursormode(fig);
    while all(cur_pos==old_pos)
        pause(0.25);
        ci = getCursorInfo(dcm);
        if ~isempty(ci)
            cur_pos = ci.Position;
        end
    end
    display(cur_pos);
    old_pos = cur_pos
    datacursormode off
    questdlg('Question?');
end
```

Without the dialog this code allows the user to select as many points as needed without getting confused (simply comment the questdlg call to see).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/261679), I needed to delete the data cursors with the following line:

```
delete(findall(fig,'Type','hggroup'));
```